# apply bootstrap backgrounds to panel footers

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap-3

Panel footers should use different background colors from bootstrap 3 theme. I tried code below but all footers are gray ?
How to force bootrap to use background colors from classes in panel footers ?

Panels have initially fixed heights. 
It should be possible to resize them up to zero height.

Code below set ming-height 0 everywhere. However resizing less than one row height is ignored.

How to allow to resize to zero height also ?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<style>
  .panel-resizable {
    min-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .panel {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
</style>
<script>
  $(function() {
    $(".panel-resizable").resizable({
      minWidth: "100%",
      maxWidth: "100%",
      minHeight: 0
    });
  });
</script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class='panel'>
    <div class='panel-body panel-resizable' style='height:0.00cm'>
    </div>
    <div class='panel-footer panel-info'>PageHeader</div>
  </div>
  <div class='panel'>
    <div class='panel-body panel-resizable' style='height:9.37cm'>
    </div>
    <div class='panel-footer panel-warning'>GroupHeader str(dokumnr)+str(koopia,2)</div>
  </div>
  <div class='panel'>
    <div class='panel-body panel-resizable' style='height:0.66cm'>
    </div>
    <div class='panel-footer panel-warning'>GroupHeader str(dokumnr)+str(koopia,2)</div>
  </div>
  <div class='panel'>
    <div class='panel-body panel-resizable' style='height:0.53cm'>
    </div>
    <div class='panel-footer panel-primary'>Detail</div>
  </div>
  <div class='panel'>
    <div class='panel-body panel-resizable' style='height:0.00cm'>
    </div>
    <div class='panel-footer panel-warning'>GroupFooter</div>
  </div>
  <div class='panel'>
    <div class='panel-body panel-resizable' style='height:7.68cm'>
    </div>
    <div class='panel-footer panel-warning'>GroupFooter</div>
  </div>
  <div class='panel'>
    <div class='panel-body panel-resizable' style='height:0.00cm'>
    </div>
    <div class='panel-footer panel-default'>PageFooter</div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The contextual classes (like `panel-warning`), goes with the `panel` class, not directly with `panel-footer`. But the footer does not inherit the color, and that's just how it works.

If you don't want to add the color by hand, you could use ["contextual backgrounds"](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-backgrounds) and do something like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="panel panel-warning">
    <div class="bg-warning">
        <div class="panel-footer">Your footer</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.panel-footer { background-color: inherit; }
```

You are not being able to set the "height" to 0 because the `panel-body` has `padding`. Try removing it.

```
.panel-body { padding: 0; }
```

Comment: Thna you. It worked. How to allow change height by dragging in any place in footer. I posted it in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34665395/how-to-resize-panel-by-dragging-in-any-place-in-footer

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward approach is to override Bootstrap's styles...

```
.panel-footer {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Use pixels for the heights.