# How to change panel height by dragging in any place in footer

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui-resizable

Code below is used to change panel heights. This  can done only by placing mouse cursor to 1px wide separator line or in panel body right downer corner.

How to allow height change by holding down mouse and dragging in any place in panel footer?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<style>
  .panel-resizable {
    min-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .panel {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
</style>
<script>
  $(function() {
    $(".panel-resizable").resizable({
      minWidth: "100%",
      maxWidth: "100%",
      minHeight: 0
    });
  });
</script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class='panel'>
    <div class='panel-body panel-resizable' style='height:0.00cm'>
    </div>
    <div class='panel-footer panel-info'>PageHeader</div>
  </div>
  <div class='panel'>
    <div class='panel-body panel-resizable' style='height:9.37cm'>
    </div>
    <div class='panel-footer panel-warning'>GroupHeader str(dokumnr)+str(koopia,2)</div>
  </div>
  <div class='panel'>
    <div class='panel-body panel-resizable' style='height:0.66cm'>
    </div>
    <div class='panel-footer panel-warning'>GroupHeader str(dokumnr)+str(koopia,2)</div>
  </div>
  <div class='panel'>
    <div class='panel-body panel-resizable' style='height:0.53cm'>
    </div>
    <div class='panel-footer panel-primary'>Detail</div>
  </div>
  <div class='panel'>
    <div class='panel-body panel-resizable' style='height:0.00cm'>
    </div>
    <div class='panel-footer panel-warning'>GroupFooter</div>
  </div>
  <div class='panel'>
    <div class='panel-body panel-resizable' style='height:7.68cm'>
    </div>
    <div class='panel-footer panel-warning'>GroupFooter</div>
  </div>
  <div class='panel'>
    <div class='panel-body panel-resizable' style='height:0.00cm'>
    </div>
    <div class='panel-footer panel-default'>PageFooter</div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi, you mean you can't change the last one's height?

Comment: No. They are footers. Resizable content is above every footer incuding last one. All panel heights can changed. Height change is inconvenient: cursor should placed to 1px wide resizable line to resize. Question asks how to resize by placing cursor in any place in footer and drag: make jquery ui resizable height same as panel footer height.